# Model property not to be mapped with the database table in MVC4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying a model property not to be mapped with the database table. I've found a solution for fluent API which is

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MODEL_NAME>().Ignore(t => t.PROPERTY_NAME);
```

I am wondering whether there is any equivalent data annotations for that. 
E.g. the following one

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MODEL_NAME>().Property(t => t.PROPERTY_NAME).IsRequired();
```

can be written as

```
[Required]
public string PROPERTY_NAME{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `[NotMapped]` attribute